# How to make glossary put a full name of an acronym in the beginning of each chapter

Tags: sectioning, glossaries

I am looking for a way I could make glossary to put a full name of acronym in the beginning of each chapter.

Here is my code sample:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disk}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}
\gls{cd} is a...
\chapter{B}
\gls{cd} is a...

\end{document}
```

It is compiled into:

> **Chapter 1**
>
> A
>
> compact disk (CD) is a ...
>
> **Chapter 2**
>
> B
>
> CD is a...  //<- should be *compact disk (CD)*

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use either `\glsreset{cd}` before the second `\gls{cd}` to reset it (there is also `\glsresetall`) or use `\glsfirst{cd}` to typeset it like it would be the first use. See the `glossaries` manual for all the details.

Comment: Yeah, this was easier with the least modifications. I simply added \glsresetall in the beginning of each chapter.

Answer (score 15):

Resetting all glossary entries at chapter starts may be automated by using the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package and appending `\glsresetall` to the definition of `\chapter`.

EDIT: See section 9.2 of the `titlesec` manual on how to emulate the sectioning command definitions of the standard classes.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disk}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}[\glsresetall]

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}
\gls{cd} is a...
\chapter{B}
\gls{cd} is a...

\end{document}
```